# Rigorous separation of variables.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ denote an open, non-empty subinterval of the real line. We're given functions:

$$f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \;\;g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$$

Now suppose we're interested in finding the set $A$, defined below, by the method of separation of variables. Basically, this involves finding the sets $B$ and $C$ (also defined below) and then using the fact that $A = B \cup C$.

> **Question.** What constraints on $f$ and $g$ allow us to conclude that $A = B \cup C$?

**Definitions.**

- $A = $ the set of all differentiable functions $y : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying

$$y'(x) = f (x) g(y(x)).$$

- $B = $ as above, except we demand the stronger condition:

$$\forall x \in I, g(y(x)) \neq 0\qquad \frac{y'(x)}{g(y(x))} = f(x).$$

- $C = $ the set of all constant functions $y : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of the form $$y(x) = c,$$ such that $c \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $g(c)=0$.

Comment: @CABJ, thanks for the bounty buddy.

Comment: I really need to know this stuff, so let's hope someone can answer it!

Comment: @CABJ, me too man. I've been needing to know this stuff for over a year now! Unfortunately, its hard to find information about calculus that is intended for those with cautious minds and a love of rigour.

Answer (score 3):

I have written a long Section of a Chapter on this, in my ODEs book, but it is in Greek. If you understand I can send it to you. The spirit is the following: How to make *separation of variables* rigorous.

However, I wish to make a comment. There are solutions which do not belong in your sets when uniqueness is violated. For example: Let the equation
$$
y'=\lvert y\rvert^{1/2}.
$$
Then one solution of the above is
$$
\varphi(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}0 & \text{if} & x\le 0, \\ x^2/4 & \text{if} & x>0.\end{array}\right.
$$
Note that that $g(\varphi(x))$ vanishes for $x\le 0$, and is positive for $x>0$.

Comment: Giasou Yiorgos - funny coincidence, I'm Greek too, but unfortunately, not too familiar with the mother tongue (3rd gen), certainly not enough to understand mathematics written in it. Do you know of any English resources where similar issues are addressed? On a related note, it might be worth translating your book into English; perhaps market it as "Ordinary Differential Equations, Done Rigorously" or some such. There's definitely people out there who would really appreciate this kind of thing.

Comment: I wasn't able to comment until today (the bounty took off my little reputation...). I think this question hasn't been understood properly. What we (goblin and I) are seeking is theory needed for not having your example... Unfortunately I can't even understand a single word from greek, but I'll give you the bounty in order to encourage you to translate your wonderful book into english (or spanish, french, portuguese). Think about us poor non-greek speakers who can't learn from bad books...